# Issue with Redis install - geohash-int/geohash.o

Tags: makefile, redis

I have this problem below when try to install Redis 3.2.1:

```
[root@clj-lc-test01 redis-3.2.1]# make
cd src && make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/redis-3.2.1/src'
LINK redis-server
cc: ../deps/geohash-int/geohash.o: No such file or directory
cc: ../deps/geohash-int/geohash_helper.o: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [redis-server] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/redis-3.2.1/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Could someone point me into the right direction?
I've seen errors like this and the solution have been to cd to deps and run make ... problem.

What should I run here?

Thank you,
Gabriel

Comment: Try running `make distclean all`

Answer (score 9):

I have solved it by going to deps folder and run make geohash-int

Thank you!

Gabriel